# Getting around base class constructor initialization, a bad habit?

Tags: c++, opengl, inheritance, constructor

I have a base class in an OpenGL project which represents 3DModel in general. Now I want to create a more specialized class that will inherits from 3DModel. My problem is the mandatory base class constructor call in the initialization list. Is there a *proper* way to delay this call until I've done some computation in the derived constructor?

Here's the important parts of the code:

```
class 3DModel {
public:
    3DModel(std::vector<...> vertices){ ... };
    [...]
private:
    std::vector<...> vertices;
    [...]
};

class Cylinder : public 3DModel {
public:
    Cylinder(float top_bottom_ratio, float base_diameter);
    [...]
};

//.cpp

Cylinder(float top_bottom_ratio, float base_width)
:3DModel(...) //<---- Mandatory
{
    //I would like to calculate the cylinder vertices here
    //and then feed them to the 3DModel constructor
}
```

Right now, I'm thinking of creating a dummy 3DModel() constructor and then call methods inside the derived constructor to modify the attributes of the base class. But this sounds really weird and it'll create a danger zone in the constructor where the object will be invalid for a few moment.

Another solution would be to thrash this class and simply do the computation inside the main program and use 3DModel constructor. But this is a sad solution and ruins the black-box approach.

Do you have any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the calculation into a helper function. Ideally, make it static, so you can't accidentally access unititialized base class values.

```
class Cylinder : public 3DModel {
public:
    Cylinder(float top_bottom_ratio, float base_diameter);
    [...]
private:
    static calculateVertices(std::vector<...> vertices);
};

//.cpp

Cylinder(float top_bottom_ration, float base_width)
:3DModel(calculateVertices(top_bottom_ratio, base_width))
{
}

std::vector<...> Cylinder::calculateVertices(float top_bottom_ratio, float base_width) {
    // calculate and return vertices here
}
```

You could also opt for composition instead of inheritance, where `Cylindar` *has a* `3DModel` instead of *being* a `3DModel`. (It would probably need to *be* something else, e.g. a `Renderable` that has a `render()` method.)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I have a very minimalistic approach at the moment, my 3DModel class contains all the rendering methods, so the composition would be harder to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the classic question of base-subclass vs composite.  While the answer does give an example in the form of "base class - subclass", you really have to ask if this can't just be a class 'Cylinder' that contains the '3DModel' class.  Unless your Cylinder subclass (and any other subclass) really adds more functionality to the 3DModel class, you really should make Cylinder a composite of the 3DModel class.

Comment: I will have to think about this. I don't have a lot of experience with composition, I choose inheritance by default when I want to reuse the code unless it is a very obvious concept (e.g. a vector is composed of points).

Comment: Based on your additional comments, it seems that you ARE adding more functionality to 'Cylinder' so subclassing is the way to go.  Good Luck.